# ftp software connection issue to vmware archlinux

Tags: ftp, vmware, arch-linux, openssh

I have set up ArchLinux as my server on vmware. (for practice purpose)

openssh has been installed and started.

Using **ip addr**, I have

[image]

**192.168.106.128  port 24** is what I need.

Now I need to connect to that server using cuteftp, but failed.

The error info returns **The remote host actively refused the attempt to connect to it.**

Lots of attempts have been made, but no luck.

Can someone please explain and give me a solution?

Comment: Why would it be port 24? Where did you configure that? What FTP software are you using? OpenSSH is not an FTP server.

Comment: I want to set up  a gdb server

Comment: After many efforts, I finally understand I need a FTP server. I just installed vsftpd